# Can someone explain this code? Permutation code

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am working on a project. I found this code regarding permutations on the Interwebz. I would like to use it as a basis for writing my own code. However, I don't really understand what is going on in the code. Could anybody lend me a hand and explain what the code is doing exactly?

```
public void permutations(String prefix, String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0)
        System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           permutations(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, n));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `permutations` is taking in a String `prefix` and a String `s` as its parameters. 
The `int` type `n` is being set to the length of the String `s`. (length of a String being how many characters it contains).

Now we move on to the `if`-`else` statements. The `if` statement is saying, if the length of `s` is 0, that is, `s` is a blank String and does not contain any information, then we are simply printing the String `prefix` instead to the console. The method will then skip over the `else` part and execute the code after the `permutations` method.

If the `if` statement's conditions are not met, we are going to run the `else` statement is saying, for each character in the String `s`, we are going to append (add) that character at the end of `prefix`, so for example, if `prefix` was originally "hello" and the character was 'U', we would get `prefix` to be "helloU". After we are finished appending all of the characters in `s`, we are going to be using the result as the new `prefix` String.

For the other parameter, the String `s`, we are going to be taking part of the String, from character 0 (inclusive) to character at position `i` (exclusive). Please note that the String indexes start at 0 and go up to (The length of the String - 1). We are also taking the part of the String from the character at position i + 1 (inclusive) to the last character in the String `s`. We are going to use this result as the new `s` String.

Then we would be calling the method again, and then the method would execute again with the newly defined Strings if the `else` condition is met. This would continue in a loop until the `else` condition is not met, at which point the method would stop running and we would move on to the next section of code (if it is present).

Comment: If you need me to clarify anything, don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

`p(String prefix, String s)` takes 1 character out of `s` and adds it to `prefix` and recursively continues until `s` is empty.

The `s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, n)` part extracts a character from `s`.
Assume `s = "Magic!"` and `i = 3` then `charAt(i) = 'i'`, `s.substring(0, i) = "Mag"` and `s.substring(i+1, n) = c!"`. That spilts `Magic!` into `i` and `Magc!`. Next time in the loop with `i = 4` it will result in `c` + `Magi!`. Since it does that for every character in `s` every character will be in the front in one of the recursive steps.

The call hierarchy would look like this

```
                                  / p("ab", "c") - "abc"
                 /- p("a", "bc") x
                /                 \ p("ac", "b") - "acb"
               /
              /                   / p("ba", "c") - "bac"
p("", "abc") x ---- p("b", "ac") x
              \                   \ p("bc", "a") - "bca"
               \
                \                 / p("ca", "b") - "cab"
                 \- p("c", "ab") x
                                  \ p("cb", "a") - "cba"

                 ^-- 1st for loop  ^- 2nd for      ^- 3rd one prints
```

Answer (score 1):

`permutations(prefix + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, n));`

Actually, this permutation algorithm is using the idea of

```
Switching current character with ith character.
```

Suppose we have a string `abc`. So the permutation of it is:

`abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba`

We can find that the `acb` is just switching `b` and `c` in `abc` with prefix `a`. And the `bca` is just switching `c` and `a` in `bac` with prefix `b`.

Then we just use the same idea to recursively solve permutation problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is some really confusing code, for two reasons:

1. The `prefix` argument: you should call this function with an empty string in the first argument, for example `permutations("", "ab")` to print all (both) permutations of `"ab"`.
2. The recursive call with `s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1, n)` in the second argument: note that java's `String.substring(x,y)` will *not* include the y-th character.  So this amounts to passing `s` with the y-th character deleted.

Now think what happens as you step through the `for` loop: the first argument becomes `""` concatenated with `"a"`, i.e. `"a"`, and the second argument becomes `s` with the first character deleted, i.e. `"b"`.  In the next recursive subcall, `prefix` becomes `"ab"` and the second argument becomes the empty string `""`.  So the base-case `n == 0` gets hit and we print the result `"ab"`.

Now we go to the next iteration of the for loop, `i == 1`.  Now we pass `"b"` in the first argument of our recursive subcall, and `"a"` in the second argument.  In the next recursive subcall `prefix` becomes `"ba"` and `s.length` is 0, so base case again: print `"ba"`.

It's clever, but inscrutable.